# textarea to full size

Tags: html, css, textarea

How can i make the textarea fullscreen and make the button bigger?
It should look a bit like this: http://prntscr.com/bwmcf3
The Code I use

```
<BODY>
<form method="post" action="query.php">
<textarea type="text" size="50" name="txtarea" maxlength="1000000"style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 12pt;">
</textarea>
<CENTER>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you vote this question down at least say why and what can i do better when i ask the next time.  Thanks.

Comment: try :     style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 12pt; width:100%;height:100%"

Comment: Then it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/bwmhlq and the button is missing.

Comment: button bigger means little increase to the current one

Comment: decrese height of text area height: 90% ( check it what you want )  and give style element in input submit and increase height and width for that

Comment: The answer from @NagaSaiA already helped me but thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To achieve expected result , use below

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NArRYK

With inline styling use below

```
<textarea type="text"  name="txtarea" style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 12pt;width:100%;height:100vw">
</textarea>
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/akGmYy

Comment: height should be 100vh not 100vw if you want true fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```html
<BODY>
<form method="post" action="query.php" style="height:100%">
<textarea type="text" size="50" name="txtarea" maxlength="1000000"style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 12pt; width:100%;height:95%">
</textarea>
<CENTER>
<input type="submit" style="height:100%; width:20%">
</form>
```